# Grab Data From URL Php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

The output of the URL should be in json format. I currently have:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://ffapi.fanfeedr.com/basic/api/leagues?api_key=thekeyvalue';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($items as $item) {
    print $item['id']."<br>".$item['name'];
}
```

**It gives me this error:**

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone show me?

Comment: Don't you feel you forgot to show us a variable ?

Comment: Where has the variable `$items` been declared?!

Answer (score 1):

$items is not declared, and foreach() is expecting an array.

Perhaps you meant:

```
foreach ($json as $item) {
```

(Since I can't see what your decoded output is, I can't know for sure.)